# IIS 7.0 reflect web site changes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have published a website on my windows server using IIS 7.0 and visual studio 2010. Its an asp.net project.

While publishing it I chose the option

"Allow this precompiled site to be updatable"

But what I do not know is how to update it when I change my templates/pages/IP address etc in my visual studio project files? I have to remove the corresponding App from IIS and then re-add it whenever I make changes. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still need to publish your updated pages to the new site using something like the "Copy Web Site" ability in VS.  What the option you select does is allow for dynamic compilation of the page as opposed to a static compilation.  For more information look [here](http://dotnetperls.com/precompiled-aspnet)

Comment: Ok.I will accept this as answer. I am trying to implement all options as described in the link that you posted and will write back if I have any more questions. Thanks bechbd